# Do Conan Debug and Release Build_Types have Different Package Dependencies?

Tags: c++, docker, conan

### Context:

---

I was trying to build my project on the gitlab pipeline when I ran into some issues. While running the gitlab-ci.yml in the pipeline on AWS, out of two testing sections, one of them fails on the conan install step.

**Successful section:**

```
- conan install .. --build missing -s build_type=Release
```

**Failed Section:**

```
- conan install .. --build missing -s build_type=Debug
```

The only real difference between the two seems to be the conan build_type, as both use the same docker image. I am guessing that the error I get from this is due to the build_type change, making it try to find an extra package with an extra dependency (soci & mariadb-connector).

**Error:**

```
mariadb-connector-c/3.0.10@omitted/stable: Configuring sources in /root/.conan/data/mariadb-connector-c/3.0.10/omitted/stable/source

WARN: OpenSSL/1.1.0j@conan/stable: requirement zlib/1.2.11@conan/stable overridden by mariadb-connector-c/3.0.10@omitted/stable to zlib/1.2.11 
OpenSSL/1.1.0j@conan/stable: WARN: ----------MAKE OPENSSL 1.1.0j-------------

ERROR: mariadb-connector-c/3.0.10@omitted/stable: Error in source() method, line 23
    "https://downloads.mariadb.org/f/connector-c-{0}/mariadb-connector-c-{0}-src.zip".format(self.version))
    NotFoundException: Not found: https://downloads.mariadb.org/f/connector-c-3.0.10/mariadb-connector-c-3.0.10-src.zip
```

**ConanFile:**

```
from conans import ConanFile, CMake


class ProjectConan(ConanFile):
    settings = "os", "compiler", "build_type", "arch"
    requires = "rfc/2.2@ommited/stable", "soci/3.2.3@ommited/stable", "libxml2/2.9.9", "zlib/1.2.11"
    default_options = {"qt:openssl": "False", "qt:with_sqlite3": "False",
                       "qt:with_mysql": "False", "qt:with_odbc": "False", "qt:with_pq": "False"}
    generators = "cmake"

    def requirements(self):
        if self.settings.os == "Windows":
            self.requires("libiconv/1.15@bincrafters/stable")
            self.requires("qt/5.13.2@bincrafters/stable")

    def configure(self):
        if self.settings.os == "Windows":
            self.generators.append("qt")

    def imports(self):
        if self.settings.os == "Windows":
            self.copy("*.dll", dst="bin", src="bin")
            self.copy("*.pdb", dst="bin", src="bin")
        self.copy("*.dylib*", dst="bin", src="lib")
        self.copy("*.so*", dst="lib", src="lib")
```

I did some searching online about [conan package build_types](https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/creating_packages/package_approaches.html), but was not able to understand the difference between the Debug and Release build_types from the official article. I also looked in my project conan file (above) and could not find any differences in dependencies between the debug and release build_types in it.

---

### Question:

Can Conan Release and Debug build_types have different package dependencies, and where would I find these if they do?

If they cannot have different package dependencies, what is the difference between the Release and Debug build_types?

Please let me know if there is any additional information I need to provide.

Thanks!

Comment: If anyone needs it, I can also provide the complete gitlab-ci.yml commands

Comment: Presumably the release build is available as a prebuilt package for your platform but the debug is not, the build is failing as the source location in the recipe seems to be incorrect

Comment: @AlanBirtles yes, we don’t have the mariadb 3.0.10 in the source location, but would you happen to know where I can find the recipe for the debug build-type?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every `conan install` with different configuration (settings, options) depends on different packages. As Conan has conditional dependencies, the dependency graph can be wildly different for different configurations

```
def requirements(self):
  if self.settings.build_type == "Release":
     self.requires("fastmath/1.0@myteam/channel")
```

Even if there aren't conditional dependencies, the binary packages used for every configuration are different. If the graph is using static libraries (option `shared`, by default typically `False`) the package binaries that are installed are different than if using shared libraries.

The same happens for Release and Debug packages. Though it is possible to create packages that contain both the Debug and Release artifacts, the default is that Release and Debug configurations are packaged in different packages.

In your case, the problem is that you have package for Release configuration, but not for the Debug one. The creators of that package didn't create and upload the Debug configuration.

By default Conan will also raise an Error when a binary package for your configuration is not found. Using `--build` policies, you can tell Conan to build that package from sources, which is what is happening above. When the recipe tries to build from source, the first step is calling the `source()` method, and this is trying to download some sources from the internet, and failing to do so. Effectively, the https://downloads.mariadb.org/f/connector-c-3.0.10/mariadb-connector-c-3.0.10-src.zip url throws a 404 Not found.

The recipe with that URL should be fixed to point to the right URL to be able to download the sources. It is also recommended that package binaries should in most cases be built in CI and uploaded to a server (Artifactory, the CE edition is free), not built in the developer machines.

Comment: Great explanation. So the package is potentially missing from the debug make_type? I will update the artifactory sources and try again. Additionally, if I update my requirements function with a debug requires version matching the release version, would this fix the issues?

Comment: Not clear what you mean. Even if the requirements() function is exactly the same, you will depend on 2 different package binaries. Check https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/introduction.html#binary-management and https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/getting_started.html#installing-dependencies. The recipe is the same, but every recipe can have N binaries. You really need to create the Debug version of the package binary to be able to depend on it. You can force to depend on a different one with ``-s mariadb-connector-c:build_type=Release`` but that can have link issues.

Comment: I see. I read through the answer and your comment again, and I think I understand better now. You mean that my debug package binary is missing, so it fails when it tries to find the package from the source. I will see if I can make that package, then get back to you. Thanks!

Comment: Haven't had a chance to make a solution yet, but thank you for providing a detailed response! I'll comment here with an update if I have a chance to fix things.